# filter and return multiple values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

In a react container I'd like to filter multiple values of an array and return the result if any of the values have the filtered data.

My code is returning results only what is the last in my filter list (in this case 'sanskrit').
If I changed the order of the return to:
`return (sanskrit, english)` - then it filters only the 'english' values.

Can someone please advise how I could filter both the 'sanskrit' and 'english' names in my database?
Thank you in advance.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const filteredAsanas = asanas.filter((asana) => {
    const english = asana.english_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()),
    sanskrit = asana.sanskrit_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
    return (english, sanskrit)
});
```

Here's an example of my json:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "sanskrit_name":"Navasana",
   "english_name":"Boat",
   "img_url":"placeholder for the image url"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @georg , I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `english || sanskrit`

```
const filteredAsanas = asanas.filter((asana) => {
    const english = asana.english_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()),
    sanskrit = asana.sanskrit_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
    return english || sanskrit
});
```